# Check if an array of object is exactly equal to another array that contains one of its property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these 2 arrays
The first one is fixed and does not change and contains the id of the 2nd array:

```
fixed=["123","456","789"]
```

The second can change

```
variableArray=[{name:"Joe",id:"123"},{name:"Joe",id:"456"},{name:"Joe",id:"789"}]
```

I want to return true if, even if there were some changes at the end the variable array is the same length and contains exactly the same keys of the "fixed"

**NOT VALID:**

```
fixed=["123","456","789"] 
variableArray=[{name:"Joe",id:"456"},{name:"Joe",id:"789"}]
```

return false because is missing the id "123" (and the length is also different so  is excluded by default)

**NOT VALID**:

```
fixed=["123","456","789"] 

variableArray=[{name:"Joe",id:"123"},{name:"Joe",id:"456"},{name:"Joe",id:"001"}]
```

this will return false because, even if contains 3 elements as there are in the "fixed" is missing the id "789" and have another "001" instead

Comment: [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @mplungjan mentiond, you can use [Every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
let fixed = ["123", "456", "789"];
let variableArray1 = [{
  name: "Joe",
  id: "123"
}, {
  name: "Joe",
  id: "456"
}, {
  name: "Joe",
  id: "789"
}];
let variableArray2 = [{
  name: "Joe",
  id: "123"
}, {
  name: "Joe",
  id: "456"
}, {
  name: "Joe",
  id: "001"
}]


let containsAll1 = variableArray1.every(elem => fixed.includes(elem.id));
let containsAll2 = variableArray2.every(elem => fixed.includes(elem.id));

console.log(containsAll1, containsAll2);
```